# bootstrap input group sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a series of bootstrap 4 input groups and would like them to be of the same size. In the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#sizing), they add classes like `input-group-sm` or `input-group-lg` and even though the text sizes are changed, the overall width of the input group stays the same.

That doesn't work for me:

[image: input groups]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efx7rp4n/

Source:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Long descriptive text:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Short:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I force my input groups to be of the same width ?

As this is bootstrap, there are of course tons of related questions. This one [Bootstrap input group sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044390/bootstrap-input-group-sizes) recommends adding `size=50` as attribute. No effect for me.

This one [Bootstrap input group field not sizing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802319/bootstrap-input-group-field-not-sizing-correctly) looked very similar to my problem. But I already tried adding a fixed width over css, it only makes it worse, `<div class="input-group mb-3" style="width:150px">` leads to:

[image]

Comment: I feel like you are going about this wrong.  The checkbox is not considered an input here.  Input groups are meant to pair with text inputs as an addon. For instance a checkbox attached to a text input per the examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column width class to your inputs.

For instance, 
    `<input type="text" class="col-4">`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend flex-colunm col-4">
    <label class="input-group-text flex-fill ">{{ field.label }}</label>
</div>
{{ field }}
</div>
```